# In Qualtrics, what are the limits on field names?

Tags: qualtrics, field-names

I've never used Qualtrics myself and do not need to, but my company receives Qualtrics-generated CSV data from another company, and we have to advise them about the names to use for fields/variables, such as "mobilephone".

The main thing I need to know is the maximum number of characters, but other limits (such as special characters to avoid) would be helpful. For example, would profile_field_twenty6chars be good? (The data is going into Moodle, which uses profile_field).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qualtrics has 2 different limitations to my knowledge.

1. Question names are limited to 10 characters(absurd in my opinion)
2. Question Export tags (this defaults to the question text, and is shown on the second row for csv datasets) has a limit of 200 characters.